# jquery equivalent of javascript interval function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript function

```
function addTenPercent(){
        var bar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
        setInterval(addTenPercent, 5000);
        bar.value += 10;
};
```

I am trying to include it on my jquery if else statement but with no luck

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e){
        if ($.trim($('#store').val()) === "" || $.trim($('#store').val()) === "Enter store number'(nnnn)'") {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('Please type in store number');
        }
        else {
                setInterval(function(){
                $('#progressBar').val() += 10;
                },5000);
        }
});
```

Can someone help point where did i go wrong on converting the said javascript to jquery?

Comment: The issue you are having is only on the setInterval() part?

Comment: @lucusp yes. i dont see it running just as it was on a the javascript version

Comment: is it a better approach if i just call the javascript function on the else statement?

else{ addTenPercent(); }

Comment: You can absolutely do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val()` returns the current value of the element, and you cannot modify the value by reference. guest271314's answer will work, but since it's good practice to cache your jQuery selections anyway, I suggest the following solution:

```
var progressBar = $('#progressBar')[0];
setInterval(function () {
    progressBar.value += 10;
}, 5000);
```

Notice that `progessBar` is a raw DOM element, not a jQuery object, and `progressBar.value` *is* being accessed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#progressBar').val() += 10;` not appear to set , reset `value` of element ?

`.val()` returns value of element ; `+= 10` not called as argument to `.val()` on element .

To set `value` of element , could use

`$('#progressBar').val( $('#progressBar').val() += 10 );`

or use `.val(function(index, value) {})`

---

Try substituting

```
$('#progressBar').val(function(_, v) {
  return v += 10
})
```

for

```
$('#progressBar').val() += 10;
```